# Datatype mismatch with datetime in SQL Server 2008

Tags: python, sql-server-2008, mysql-python

I am trying to save some tweets data into MS SQL Server 2008 database.

The Fields in database are :

```
[Id] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
[Created_At] [datetime] NULL,
[Text] [varchar](max) NULL
```

After getting Tweets data I try them to put them into above database table this way:

```
qry="INSERT INTO TwitterPosts(Id,Created_At,Text) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)"
x.execute(qry, (str(tweet.id), tweet.created_at.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'),str(tweet.text.encode("utf-8","ignore"))))
x.commit()
```

The created_At date-time is not getting stored due to datatype mismatching.

**Error:**

```
(242, 'The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n')
```

What datatypes should I choose here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert `datetime` instead of `str`

```
x.execute(qry, (str(tweet.id), tweet.created_at, str(tweet.text.encode("utf-8","ignore"))))
```

Comment: @yurri   tweet.createdd_at is already giving datetime values like this ... datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 15, 1, 19, 53)     and I am directly trying to put that into datetime datatype of sql. but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the datetime format in the query:

qry="INSERT INTO TwitterPosts(Id,Created_At,Text) VALUES(%s,convert(datetime, '%s',101),%s)"

You must also change the strftime('%d-%m-%Y') to strftime('%m/%d/%Y') for US datetime 101  format
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.90).aspx